# Spanner DB query on Array type column

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I wanted to write a select query to fetch all the records but I am getting error if I try to match more than one type against a array type column, for example
Below query is working

```
SELECT * FROM Car where ("Ford") IN UNNEST (cartype)
```

But this query is failing

```
SELECT * FROM Car where (["Ford","Honda","Suzuki"]) IN UNNEST (cartype)
```

> HTTPError 400: {"code":3, "message":"First argument to IN UNNEST of type ARRAY does not support equality comparison [at 1:42]\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether you want just one of the given values to be in the `cartype` array, or all, but you probably want one of these functions:

1. `ARRAY_INCLUDES_ALL`: This function returns true if all the array elements of the first array are included in the second array (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_includes_all)
2. `ARRAY_INCLUDES_ANY`: This function returns true if at least one of the array elements of the first array is included in the second array (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_includes_any)

Assuming that you want at least one to be included in the array, then your query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Car
where ARRAY_INCLUDES_ANY(cartype, ["Ford","Honda","Suzuki"])
```

Comment: thanks i was looking for the syntax, this one is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this on my end i got the same error when i tried with below query

```
SELECT * FROM Car where (["Ford","Honda","Suzuki"]) IN UNNEST (cartype)
```

Instead of the `ARRAY\_INCLUDES` function as answered by @Knut Olav Løite you can use the below query as well.

```
SELECT * FROM Car where (cartype) IN UNNEST  (["Ford","Honda","Suzuki"])
```

In above I have changed the query where comparing the array column cartype with an array literal `(["Ford","Honda","Suzuki"])`

[UNNEST](https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-unnest/) operator converts an array to a table. Here `cartype` is a table column in which these UNNEST values may appear.